# Magento2: We have unassigned an attribute from the attribute set but it is still showing on the frontend

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php, magento2.4, php-7.2

I have different Attribute Set Name they are tv,laptop and watch I have unassigned Ram in attribute in watch and Tv and assigned attribute  in Laptop but it showing Ram in Watch(attribute) and Tv and laptop it is working fine how to solve it
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @Alan, Is it a custom implementation to display the attributes on the frontend or is it a default Magento process working? could you please confirm?

Answer (score 0):

**There could be two cases:**

**Default implementation:**

If the attribute still shows on the frontend after removing the attribute from attribute set then there could be two issues:

1. indexing issue. Please execute indexing command & cache flush & then check.
2. If indexing & cache flush didn't solve the issue then goto the attribute & set the Visible on **Catalog Pages on Storefront** to **No**. and do indexing & cache flush. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

**Custom implementation:**

In this case, you will have to add additional condition into the code. like if the attribute not exists in the current attribute set then it shouldn't display the title/label & value.